# [NSOperationQueue addOperation:]: operation is finished and cannot be enqueued'

Tags: ios, objective-c

`[NSOperationQueue addOperation:]:` operation is finished and cannot be enqueued', facing this issue, how to handle it , 
When I move my app to `background` and quit it then I want to resume uploading video/initiate new request on rebooting app and restarting but it keep on showing `[NSOperationQueue addOperation:]: operation is finished and cannot be enqueued'`

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You'd have to show us the life cycle of this operation, but the error is telling you it was already started. Maybe you called `start`. Maybe you already enqueued it and it finished. Maybe it is a custom subclass that was not implemented properly. It's impossible to say on the basis of the info provided.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).